# CSS first and last child elements

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am rendering 2 buttons inside a div and wanted to float one to the left and one to the right.

I assumed I could use the :first-child and last:child elements, But it seems that the css for the :first-child runs and is then over written by the :last-child tag

I have also tried using the :nth-child(1) selectors

Here is an example: http://www.bootply.com/elg2cP9Usp

Edit: Correct working code, thanks all:

```
<div class="container"> 
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default 1">On</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default 2">Off</button>
 </div>

/* CSS used here will be applied after bootstrap.css */
.container {
        width: 100%;
        padding 25px 40px;
    }

    .container > .btn {
        min-width: 35%;   
    }

    .container > .btn:first-child {
        float: left;   
    }

    .container > .btn:last-child {
        float: right;   
    }
```

Comment: your links seems wrong - link for a new script on bootply :)

Comment: haha just noticed that and added the correct link.

Comment: Please add the relevant [MCVE] code to your question; don't just link to it or as soon as the external site dies, falls over or reorganises its content, this question loses all value and becomes immediately nonsensical (at best).

Comment: Makes me think that people should learn HTML/CSS before using Bootstrap.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```css
/* CSS used here will be applied after bootstrap.css */

.container {
  width: 100%;
  padding 25px 40px;
}
.container > .btn {
  min-width: 35%;
}
.btn:first-child {
  float: left;
}
.btn:last-child {
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">On</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Off</button>
</div>
```

Wrong approach buddy, target the buttons..!!

Answer (score 3):

The `:first-child` notation is kind of misleading. You need to apply it directly to your `.btn` class.

To get the desired result try:

```
.container .btn:first-child {
    float: left;   
}

.container .btn:last-child {
    float: right;   
}
```

To avoid any group of buttons to behave like this I narrowed the selector down to `.container .btn`.

Here is your [updated example](http://www.bootply.com/m0RGeClkWK).

Answer (score 1):

You might want to use the `first-of-type` and `last-of-type` selectors which allows you to select the elements by their type; `button` in this case:

```
.container button:first-of-type {
    float: left;   
}

.container button:last-of-type {
    float: right;   
}
```

[A fork of your code is here.](http://www.bootply.com/EVmP5KcDNW)